# Virtual machine error kvm

Tags: android, kvm

I am trying to run the android sdk emulator on **Ubuntu 14.04** with AMD A6-3670 processor and I get the error message

```
/home/jeff/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_22_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none -qemu -m 512 -enable-kvm
ko:/home/jeff/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator64-arm: invalid option -- '-enable-kvm'
```

I'm a complete novice when it comes to virtual machines.

Can anyone tell me what it means and give me some pointers to getting it going?

---

**PS:** kvm is loaded and I appear to be a member of kvm

```
jeff@Snowdon:~$ sudo addgroup `whoami` kvm
The user `jeff' is already a member of `kvm'.
```

Comment: It superficially appears to me that the `emulator64-arm` application is complaining about the presence of a *command-line parameter,* `-enable-kvm`, that has been supplied to it. Nothing more or less. I see no obvious connection to "what Unix/Linux 'groups' you belong to."  Thus, `addgroup` is most likely a red-herring. You didn't post the command-line that was issued (or, that was issued *for* you ...).

Comment: Thanks Pedro. I'm running the Android-SDK app and I'm not sure how to find the command-line statement

Comment: Well. OK. I can see an '-enable-kvm' in the command issued by the emulator (see my code 'emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_22_x86' posted above). But the SDK did thta. Is it a setting anywhere I can change?

Answer (score 0):

kvm is basically an optimization that allows to run VM guest binaries directly on the host CPU, without any translation. You have an x86_64 CPU (AMD) and you are trying to run an ARM emulator, so kvm will not help. Kvm only works when the guest VM and the host CPU have the same instruction set.

Just leave out the kvm option. Qemu can emulate ARM binaries on an x86_64 CPU. It will not be as fast as with kvm.